# Finding DisplayObject to use in PopUpManager

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am creating an extension for a Flex Web Client.  The way my extension is introduced is through a menu item in the UI.  When the user selects the action from the menu, it will run my specific ActionScript method.

I would like to have my ActionScript method create a pop up using PopUpManager.  The issue I am running into is that the first argument for PopUpManager.createPopUp is a DisplayObject.  Since I am going straight into a AS method, I cannot use an inherit DisplayObject (aka 'this').

I am looking for a way from the AS method to find or access a reference to a parent/root DisplayObject.  Is this possible?  I am pretty new to Flex/ActionScript, so I may also have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on here.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Show us some code, usualy if your function is inside a class that inherits from displayObject and it is added to the stage, then this.stage and this.parent point at the stage and parent respectively.
If not you will have to store a reference to stage/parent somewhere or pass them to your function.

Comment: After talking to a few coworkers, I was turned onto this solution:

import mx.core.FlexGlobals
...
var popup:IFlexDisplayObject = 
     popUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as 
     DisplayObject, MyPopUp, false);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with a Self-Answer for anyone else that is searching for this topic, from my earlier comment

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals
var popup:IFlexDisplayObject = popUpManager.createPopUp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as   DisplayObject, MyPopUp, false); PopUpManager.centerPopUp(popup);
```